# How to retrieve data child?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble to retrieve data from Firebase database

[image]

in this DB i need to get the field "TYPE", but dunno how to identify child component because is a random key

```
 firebase.database().ref('Sveglie/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
              // console.log(snapshot)
               this.setState({ ret : snapshot})
                console.log(this.state.ret)
```

With this i get the entire section.
How to fix ?

Comment: Do you know anything about that child nodes that you're trying to retrieve? If you don't know anything about it, all you can do is retrieve all children for a user.

Comment: Actually not , I thought there was a wayto get the child if type = shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only a specific child node for a specific user, you'll need to know something that identifies the user (which you do), and something that identifies the node. From the question it isn't clear if you have the latter. If you don't, then all you can do, is process all child nodes for a user.

Something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('Sveglie/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let states = "";
  snapshot.forEach((child) => { // loop over each child node of the user's node
    if (child.hasChildren()) { // ensure we only process the child nodes with child properties
      console.log(child.key); // "-Lpc_vqU...-aNcl"
      console.log(child.val()); // { DestinationForUserNotify: "... ", ... }
      console.log(child.val().type); // "shareD"

      states = states + child.val().type + "\n";
    }
  })
  this.setState({ ret : states })
})
```

Comment: Actually the result is : https://i.imgur.com/P9BTBmu.png
Seems the key is the user ID

Comment: Changed shapshot.val into child.val to get the proper result. Thank you very much for help =)